# Spring security securing home page when permitted to all

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Done a lot of research with the below code. I am using an Oauth2 login using github Oauth, all that is working great, but I am unable to permit anyone and everyone access the home page. Kindly tell me what I am missing. This is in spring 3.0.2 version.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(reqmatcher ->
            {
                try {
                    reqmatcher
                            .requestMatchers("/")
                            .permitAll()
                            .and().authorizeHttpRequests()
                            .requestMatchers("/**")
                            .authenticated()
                            .and()
                            .oauth2Login();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });

    return http.build();
}

}
```

I was expecting that home url loads without the user being logged in.

Below code is working in Spring 2.7.11

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and().oauth2Login();

    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Try `anyRequest()` instead of `requestMatchers("/**")`